# How do I center <div> tag using CSS?

Tags: css

Code thus far:

```
#master {
position: absolute;
height: auto;
width: 1000px;
min-height: 50px;
}
```

I want to center the  tag horizontally, but not the task.
What code do I need to add to do this?

Comment: You can horizontally-center a `div` inside a parent `div` by giving the `div` a width, and then adding `margin: 0 auto;`: http://jsfiddle.net/spikey/FLL5Z/

Answer (score 4):

Add the following to your css rules

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

This will horizontally center block level elements.